# Quotes in grep in bash with arguments

Tags: bash, grep, quotes

I have this script that find some text (hello) in all the pdfs in the current directory

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep "hello" -iF --with-filename --label="{}" --color' \;
```

I want to use the first argument instead a fixed string.
I replaced `"hello"` by `"$1"`, `"\"$1\""`, and other combinations to no avail.

I think it is a problem with the double-quotes around the `$1` and inside the single quotes.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: `pdfgrep` is good...

Comment: Do not ever, **ever** use `{}` inside the `...` part of a `sh -c '...'` string. Anyone who can give you a PDF with `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` in its name can give you a very bad day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A safer version of this code looks like:

```
text_to_search_for="hello"
text_to_search_for="$text_to_search_for" find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    pdftotext "$file" - | grep "$text_to_search_for" -iF --with-filename --label="$file" --color
  done
' sh {} +
```

---

Note:

- Putting `text_to_search_for="$text_to_search_for"` *before `find` on the same line* means that we export the variable `text_to_search_for` to the environment only for the duration of that one command.
- We pass the text to search for as an environment variable into the copy of `find` we're running, which in turn allows it to be inherited by the copy of `sh` that `find` starts.
- We **do not ever** use `{}` inside the string passed as an argument to `sh -c`, but only use it in generating arguments to that command. This is absolutely critical for both portability and security reasons; the POSIX standard for `find` does not guarantee that `{}` will work when a substring rather than a complete string, and more importantly, `{}` substituted into code means that the filenames you're iterating over can be used to attack your system.
- We use `sh {} +` to pass multiple filenames to each copy of `sh`, and `for file do` to assign each one in term to the variable `file`. (The `sh` is a placeholder for `$0`, so the names from `find` are assigned to `$1` and later; `$0` is used in error messages, so whatever placeholder is used in that position should be something that makes sense if printed alongside an error).